# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'water.mat'

Tags: python

I am running the following Python codes but received the below error:

```
 import scipy.io as sio

 dataset = sio.loadmat('water.mat')


 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'water.mat'
```

Does the 'water.mat' file exist in scipy? Is there any file existing equivalent to 'water.mat?'

Comment: The "water.mat' file was part of teaching material of a teacher who taught Machine Learning course. I tried to find the same file in https://github.com/fengdu78/Coursera-ML-AndrewNg-Notes/tree/master/code and downloaded the file but the file shows Microsoft Access Table Shortcut. Where can the same file be retrieved for my own practice of Python programming?

Comment: According to Mr Andrew Ng's github information, the training dataset is named "ex5data1.mat" but not "water.mat." After I renamed the "water.mat" file to "ex5data1.mat" and ran the Python codes again, coding was running ok. So, this question can be closed.